# What is an alt handler, talking about the Objective-C runtime system exception handling?

Tags: objective-c, exception, objective-c-runtime

Looking at the Objective-C runtime system source code, especially at the [objc-exception.mm](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-exception.mm) file, I found the expression "alt handler" and functions that deal with alt handlers. I have no idea what it is, but according to the file comments, if the runtime library is compiled with no alt handler support, there is only the zerocost implementation, which I also don't know what is.

So, what is an alt handler and what is a zerocost exception handling when we are talking about the Objective-C runtime library?

Comment: [Zero-Cost @try Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/Exceptions64Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009044-SW2)

Comment: Please dont take this the wrong way, just wondering: How familiar are you with the way exception handlers work? I only ask because I cannot figure out how familiar you are with them from your question.

Comment: @Ryan I know that when an exception is thrown, the function that tries to catch it (the personality routine, I guess) unwinds the stack in order to find a frame in which there is a handler for it. This handler is related to the catch clause. If no handler is found, the program is terminated. Otherwise, the program jumps to the catch clause's corresponding function. This is the shortest I could manage...

Comment: Not a problem Luis, it will help me help you with an answer. Look for it shortly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Objective-C runtime library allows the developer to specify functions to be called for each stack frame while the system is unwinding the stack for the second time, in the cleanup phase, after it found a catch clause for the just-thrown exception.

So, for those who are familiar with both the Unwind Library and the ObjC exception handling system, when the Objective-C personality routine (`__objc_personality_v0`) is called for the current stack frame's Unwind Context, the ObjC system checks whether there is an alt handler for that context. If an alt handler is found, it gets called first. Thereafter, since the ObjC exception handling machinery uses the C++ ABI to unwind the stack, the cxx personality function (`__gxx_personality_v0`) gets called. However this is done only if the objc personality routine is being called in the cleanup phase, not in the search phase. So, if no catch clause is found for the current exception, no alt handler is called, if any.

About the zero-cost part, the cxx personality function uses a zero-cost exception handling. Thus, if the runtime library is compiled with no alt handler support, there is only the zero-cost implementation, since `__gxx_personality_v0` is called anyway.

The Objective-C library public API provides two functions to add and remove an alt handler for a specific Unwind Context: `objc_addExceptionHandler` and `objc_removeExceptionHandler`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Luis, you are right in that there is a function stored upon which, when an exception is thrown, the function is called, but you are incorrect that the program is automatically terminated if an exception handler is not found (it's a little bit more interesting than that). The moment an exception is triggered (bad memory read, div by 0, whatever), the operating system (windows/*nix) looks through its chain of installed exception handlers and calls the first one it finds (the most recent one installed via a `try{}catch{}` block. Now if one has not been programmed in, the default handler is executed, which in most cases ends the program and performs a stack unwind. In kernel mode programming, if you do not install your own handler though, you can segfault the entire system, the default exception handler is provided to user mode programs only for the most part.

I could write a really REALLY long answer for you, but I found a perfect site for you that I think helps answer your questions which will aid in the understanding of the different ways that you can implement exception handlers at the compiler level, specifically answering your "zero-cost" exception handler and the SJLJ techniques notes in the code too:

[Exception Handling Explained](http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the attention, Ryan. I noticed by your answer and by the questions you asked me above that you tried your best to answer me. However, unfortunately, maybe you didn't get exactly what I meant. Actually, I'm not interested in the exception handling process itself. The point is I was surfing the Objective-C runtime library source code and I found the expression "alt handler". I have no idea what it is, but it seems to be an alternative to the zerocost C++ based exception handling implementation. So, in short, what is an "alt handler" or what is "alt handling"?

Comment: I think they are saying it from the aspect of alternative handler implementations, as in, is it the zero cost, or set jump long jump, or some other method. Sorry if i took too short of an approach on you, I didn't want to come off cocky, or talking down, I learn just as much from trying to help people out (I usually learn along the way lol)